# How can I install Python tool for visual studio 2015?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

I was trying to install python tool for visual studio 2015, well it should have been an easy task just go on new project and choose python and visual studio would have downloaded it for you, but there some error coming or what is it i don't understand. What i am doing is as follows:
Step 01:
[I went here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DWjg.png)

Step 02:
A box appears seeking for the permission to install.(It is says add support for python projects, support, debugging and more) and When I click on the install button step 03 window appears.

Step 03:
[This error comes up and nothing happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkDXZ.png)

What should i Do?
And yeah i need to install cpython.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of writing, the current release for Python Tools for Visual Studio 2015 is version 2.2, and can be [downloaded here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/v2.2). Other releases, including development releases and versions for older versions of Visual Studio can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases).

In order to install the tools, you should just download the MSI for your Visual Studio version and execute it. The installer will guide you through everything. Once it’s done, you just need to restart Visual Studio once and the tools will be available.

You also need a Python interpreter, which you can find on [python.org](https://www.python.org/).

Comment: Thanks it worked, and if you could tell me why do people downvote suh questions here? I am new here and facing problem with people downvoting my question, which i don't find to be downvoted.
And I can't upvote your question as i don't have 15 reputation right now.

Comment: I assume that's because the answer could have been easily found via Google. So people criticize your effort to find an answer on your own. That being said, if this answer solved your problem, please accept the answer to mark the question as resolved.