# How do you run a python program in visual studio

Tags: python, json

Whenever I hit the **f5 key** to run a program a new file called `launch.json` opens and I don't know what to do from there. Does anyone know hat to do and no this is no the same as how do I install python for visual studio.
This is what `launch.json` looks like.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "program": "${file}",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python Console App",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "program": "${file}",
            "externalConsole": true,
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "DjangoDebugging"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Watson",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/console.py",
            "args": [
                "dev",
                "runserver",
                "--noreload=True"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Python tool for visual studio 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032209/how-can-i-install-python-tool-for-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: thanks to Mushahid kahn

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant VS Code. If that's the case, this is an auto generated file where you can configure what will happen when you press `F5`. If you save that file as is and then switch back to your `main.py` or whatever python file you want to debug and press again `F5` you will start debugging with a breakpoint on your first executable line.